# AVD won't start up

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I created a simple Android app in Eclipse ADT, just a simple `Hello World`. The IDE I am using was downloaded from the Android web site, seems it's based on Eclipse Juno and has the ADT plugin. My OS is Windows 7, 64 bit.

OK, then I created an AVD in the IDE (from a Nexus 5 template; just lowered the memory to 512MB).

The problem is that I keep getting this error when I try to start the AVD (with no app in it). Seems like it's in some loop and keeps printing this in the LogCat and the AVD screen is just black.

1. What might be wrong?
2. How does one normally troubleshoot such issues? I am new to Android (but not to Java).

```
11-21 22:50:01.740: A/libc(1275): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x4fb (code=-6), thread 1275 (surfaceflinger)
11-21 22:50:04.030: W/AudioFlinger(1278): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
11-21 22:50:04.060: W/AudioFlinger(1278): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
11-21 22:50:04.060: W/AudioFlinger(1278): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
11-21 22:50:04.060: E/AudioFlinger(1278): no wake lock to update!
11-21 22:50:04.090: E/AudioFlinger(1278): int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
11-21 22:50:04.090: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(1278): could not open HW module r_submix
11-21 22:50:05.970: W/InterfaceController(1325): Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
11-21 22:50:06.530: E/SurfaceFlinger(1326): hwcomposer module not found
11-21 22:50:06.530: E/SurfaceFlinger(1326): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
```

Comment: Definitely not an answer, just a note: I think almost everyone can agree with me that AVD is the worst android emulator in the world. When I used it, it was painfully slow and heavy, in my machine (3rd gen Intel i7/8gb ram/ssd) it took over a minute just to start up, and everything was buggy. As per your question, I hope you'll find a solution. In the meantime, you might want to look for other better-performing emulators, such as BlueStacks or Genymotion. Both will be read as an android device in debug mode, so you'll be able to use them for testing your app.

Comment: Did you by chance using normal android project with wearable avd?

Comment: @AtillaOzgur Yes, the CPU was selected as Android Wear. Is that bad? What should I choose?

Comment: @BackSlash If everything is so buggy as it seems why do we have it there in all those UI menus/views etc. Practically it doesn't work, right?

Comment: Choose phone one instead of wearable. I think their hello world projects are different.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur I have two options for CPU: Wear or Intel Atom. I think I tried both with pretty much the same success. When I try Intel Atom, I get this: "ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!" But that thing is installed in my Android SDK package manager.

Comment: My min, max, target version are all set to API 20 (Android 4.4.W.2). Is that bad too?

Comment: @peter.petrov try to create a different AVD with phone values.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur OK, I will, I think I see what you mean. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Why do we have it? I think the answer would be "because it's the official emulator from Google". I'm not using AVD since more than a year now, maybe they improved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using Android 4.4W which (as I realized later) is the so-called Android Wear and is applicable to very specific devices only (like watches e.g.). After switching to the normal Android 4.4.2, the issue described in my question disappeared.